# Check If File Is Available on FTP Server

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ftp, wget

I need to check and see if a certain file is available for download on an FTP server. I've been using `wget`'s --spider option to achieve this with HTTP but, this only works with 404 errors, which FTP does not use.

**Current Code (Not Working):**

```
file1="12345.tar"
abc1="http://some.website/data/${file1}"

if wget --no-cache --spider --user=username --password='password' ${abc1} >/dev/null 2>&1; then
echo "File ${abc1} exists. Let's get it!"
bash run.sh
else
echo "File ${abc1} doesn't exist. Exiting script..."
exit 0
fi
```

How can I check ("spider") to see if a file is available on an FTP server? I know that the "404" version of FTP is 550 (No such file or directory).

Answer (score 2):

**For FTP**:

Response code: Service ready for new user (220)

Response code: 150 Here comes the directory listing / opening binary data connection

**For HTTP**:

replace 220 or 150 with HTTP/1.1 200 OK

```
#!/bin/bash

url="ftp://path/to/some/file.something"

function validate_url(){

    if [[ `wget -S --spider $url 2>&1 | grep '150'` ]]; then exit_status=$?; fi
    if [[ $exit_status == 0 ]]; then
            echo "FTP location exists"
    elif [[ $exist_status == 1 ]]; then
            echo "FTP location not available"
    fi
}

validate_url
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You need to check first for 550. If your grep catches 550, the file is not there, otherwise it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was able to get working:

```
file1="12345.tar"
abc1="http://some.website/data/${file1}"

check=`wget --no-cache --spider --user=username --password='password' ${abc1} 2>&1 | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 24 | tail -1`

if [ ${check} -eq "No" ]; then
echo "File ${abc1} doesn't exist. Exiting script..."
exit 0
else
echo "File exists!"
fi
```